# deleting a 'file' under /proc or /dev

Tags: rm, chroot, proc

I am using a cowdancer/debootstrap setup to generate a chroot.

Of course, as I iterate, I generate some chroot configurations that are bad.

I have found myself in an awkward situation where I have a slew of files under /proc that are refusing to be deleted.

When I `sudo rm -rf z_needs_to_be_deleted`, I get a ton of messages that look analogous to this:

```
rm: cannot remove 'z_needs_to_be_deleted/var/cache/pbuilder/build/cow.13620/
proc/6352/task/6358/loginuid':  Permission denied
```

How do I kill off this chroot?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`/proc` and (usually) much of `/dev` are read only kernel-generated "filesystems".  You don't delete them, you just `umount` the filesystem.  If `rm -r /proc/6352` worked, it would have to be semantically equivalent to `kill -9 6352`, since it's really just presenting information about pid 6352, not actual files anywhere.

Use `mount` to see what mounted filesystems are under the `chroot` and `umount` them before removing any files.  This is perhaps even more important when it's a `bind` mount, since `rm -r` would remove the original files outside the jail.

Comment: On Linux, `/dev` is typically a writable instance of *tmpfs*, maintained by udev.

Comment: @grawity: I was thinking more of things like `/dev/fd`, which is typically a symlink to `/proc/self/fd`. IIRC there are some ALSA symlinks around as well.